# Azure How can I call internal API Management service by private IP inside VNET

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-virtual-network, azure-dns

I created VNET in Azure. I put in one subset internal API Management which call Azure Function outside of the VNET and in another one Virtual machine. When I tried to call API Management I got a 503 exception. And if I try to ping private IP from the VM it doest work. 
The other solution was to create Azure private link but in this case, I got the info by the link but did not be able to ping or call by private IP(got 400)
My solution was to run the web app instead of the AF in the VM because VM can be easily called by private IP in VNET.
How can I call API Management and other azure services(Azure private link) by private API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-internal-vnet#apim-dns-configuration),

> **API Management service does not listen to requests coming from IP
>   addresses**. It only responds to requests to the hostname configured on
>   its service endpoints. These endpoints include gateway, the Azure
>   portal and the Developer portal, direct management endpoint, and Git.

You only could access API management service via hostname instead of private IP in an **internal** mode API Management. For this mode, you have to manage your own routing. If you use a custom DNS server in a virtual network, you can also create A DNS records and access these endpoints from anywhere in your virtual network.

Comment: Is this mean that I can't call API management by IP and only can call it by URL inside of VNET?

Comment: Yes, more specifically you need to use Private DNS zones: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-overview